# Android Studio 4.1.2 - Dart And Flutter is not installed in "flutter doctor"

Tags: android-studio, flutter, plugins

I've recently installed android studio 4.1.2 with flutter 1.22.6
even though I installed flutter and dart plugins in android studio the result of 'flutter doctor' command was as follows.

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 
  10.0.18362.30], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 
  30.0.2)
[!] Android Studio
     X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
     X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] Connected device
! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

**Now for clear error act as below (Steps worked for me):**

```
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"
flutter doctor -v
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem in Flutter config detection. If you start Android Studio and plugins installed, you can use it and all functionality will works fine. You can find solutions in [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67986).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the Flutter SDK.
You can ignore it. Everything works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for getting that error is because of the Android version you are using. If you should run:

**flutter doctor -v**,

You should get the Android version flutter is trying to check the configuration for.
In my case, it shows Android Studio version 4.1.0 even though i have Android Studio 4.1.2 installed with the required plugins. So, as long as it keeps expecting that Android studio version but with a different version installed, you should be getting same error. So, i think the solution to that is to get the Android version flutter doctor displays or probably wait for the next stable release of flutter that supports Android version 4.1.2.